# How to get counts of each value from every column from a very large table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large table that is around 200+ million records with hundreds of columns.  I would like to get counts of each value (most columns contain anywhere from 2 to 15 different values) in each column, and possibly even breaking it down by state (there is a state field in the table).  I know how to get counts for the values, but I'm looking for the most efficient method that is least likely to completely kill the server.  I have other databases on the server that I don't want to impact too much.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing doing something like this:

```
select col, val, count(*)
from t cross apply
     (values ('col1', col1), ('col2', col2), . . . ) v(col, val)
group by col, val
order by col, count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the columns you are referencing are likely NOT indexed any query run is likely to consume a fair amount of resources.

I would suggest you try something along the lines of

```
select state,'colname',colname,count(*) as cnt 
from tablename
group by state,colname
```

'colname' being a static name that represents the column you are reporting on.

Repeat the process for each column you wish to process.